# mvc 3 issues after converting 2: model + Model + Html + not supported type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I used the conversion tool to convert to mvc 3 from mvc 2.

I create a new partial view, select razor, check "Reference script libraries" (not sure what this means), select "Link (urlme.Model)" for strongly-type, List, OK.

I get the following errors:

- List item
- The name @model does not exist in the current context
- The name Model does not exist in the current context
- The name @Html does not exist in the current context
- Element 'urlme.Model.Link' is not supported (standard c# class leftover before conversion)

Do I need to add some references??  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm stoked to use mvc 3!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you might be missing the Razor sections in `Views\Web.config`. Please compare the contents of that file with the one generated via the new project template.

Note that Eilon's v2 -> v3 upgrade tool currently only targets MVC3 Beta, so it might not do all the things necessary for RC2. I'm sure Eilon will post an updated version of that tool at some point in the future.

Comment: that did it!  I ended up creating a blank mvc 3 project, and comparing that with the project that I converted, updating the converted one as necessary with missing web config stuff.  thanks!

Comment: And what about areas? Should I have the same web.config for every area? I had this error for my root Views. Placing the web.config to \Views\ solved this problem. But for my Views in Areas/Admin/Views folder I still have this problem.

Comment: Yes. This should be done for each area as well. The current version of the upgrade tool will do this for you.